# Why is it necessary to include the return type in a function definition even if it's specified in the declaration?

Tags: c++

When you define a function in a separate cpp file, why is the return type necessary to indicate which specific function you would like to define if the compiler knows that a method cannot overload another method with the same signature who only differ by return type? Isn't foo::bar(params) enough to specify this?

**Header file**

```
class foo{
public:
void bar();
};
```

**Source file**

```
foo::bar() //equivalent to function declaration? throws error
{...}
```

Thank you

Comment: Because function definition has to have return type to be known to be a function definition (unless we are talking about special functions).

Comment: Because the function definition doesn't need to have a separate declaration.

Comment: @Galik: In case of member functions - it does. Yon can't define an undeclared member function.

Comment: @AnT Ah yes, I think my main point, which I failed to make, was why have separate rules? Why have some function definitions that can omit the return type and other function definitions that require it?

Comment: I'm not a C++ guy, but I'm guessing it is just syntax consistency.  

What if said function isn't exposed in a header file?  If they allowed it, then there would be two ways to define a function, IF, it was exposed in a header file.

Comment: C++ grammar is already complicated. Why make it even more complicated by allowing to omit return type in some cases?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I tested it and there is no warning if bar is defined with int return type. Perhaps it is lazy design or missed use case? Here's my test case http://hastebin.com/asitucuvew.cpp

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's any inherent reason that this couldn't be done, but using it would lead to inconsistency. After all, you don't have to declare a function if its definition is visible, but in that case, you'd have to include the return type. So function definitions that have a preceding declaration wouldn't need a return type, but function definitions that didn't, would. And if you removed the declaration you'd have to rewrite the definition. Altogether too much fiddling around.

EDIT: not to mention the convenience of having the return type in front of you when you're looking at the definition of the function.

Comment: Can you comment on standard? If i understand correctly, from section 8.4.1 it follows that it is optional.

Comment: @LukaRahne: How so? We know that it's not optional, so you'd have to try pretty hard to convince us that the standard says is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [*function-definition*'s grammar](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#dcl.fct.def.general-1) does mark the *decl-specifier-seq* as optional, because it needs to support constructors and the like. [\[dcl.dcl\]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#10) says "Syntactic components beyond those found in the general form of declaration are added to a function declaration to make a *function-definition*", so presumably stripping out the body should leave a valid declaration (which disallows omitting the return type), but it isn't as clear as one might like.

Comment: @T.C.: With C++ you generally need to look in a few places at once to find the valid syntax and semantics of any given construction. Clearly there are other rules prohibiting this in this context otherwise it would be valid (which it isn't).

Comment: @T.C. - yes, that grammar production says that the return type is optional. That doesn't mean that it's never required, it just means that there are some cases where it isn't. I suspect that the rule is that you can't provide a "normal" return type when you use a trailing-result-type, and that you must provide a "normal" return type when you don't. The production for function-definition is a **syntactic** constraint; syntactic constraints are **also** bound by **semantic** constraints, and that's undoubtedly where the true rule comes from. (I haven't waded through this part of the standard).

Comment: @LukaRahne - do you know of **any** compiler that allows you to define a function without a return type (aside from the long-gone implicit int from the olden days of C).

Comment: @Pete Becker. I do not know about such compiler. What I have learned about C++ is, that it is not matter what common sense provides, but what standard has to say, if one is enlightened enough to understand and that compiler is on same track. I asked that question, so I would get some more insights how to understand and read C++ standard and how language works. I don't expect to get exact answer and thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did spend some time searching through clauses 7 and 8 last night, and like I said the only thing I can find is [dcl.dcl]/10. The fact that this area was [recently refactored](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1990) doesn't help, either. Of course, if the standard doesn't spell it out cleanly, it's a bug in the standard, not the compilers.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be a design goal of C++ to eliminate all possible redundancy from programs.

That is not even a good goal to have, at least if taken to extremes.

It is useful for the same information to be repeated in two places, and have an error be flagged if they conflict.

Some programming languages have redundancy built into basic control syntax, like `while condition ; do .. if condition ; then .... end if; ... end while;` The `while` must be terminated by `end while`, and `if` by `end if`.   The compiler then knows exactly which one is missing. Proponents of such languages insist that this is better than a diagnostic about one of fifteen possible braces not being closed. :)

The return type being repeated in the definition is also helpful to the programmer in another way: the programmer doesn't have to jump to the declaration to see what the return type is.

It would actually take extra work to remove the return type in some cases. Declarations in headers can be produced by exact copy and paste. Or even with automated tools. You wouldn't want a header-generating tool to strip away the return type from your definitions.

We should question the necessity of declarations in the first place. The definition of a function is the primary artifact; the declaration is something that is just factored out for the sake of a particular compilation model. In other words, the question is "given that we have a function definition, why do we have to repeat any part of it anywhere".

Comment: I would argue if they didn't want this inconsistency, they would give a compile time warning that the function should have a return type(rather than a constructor). Since this is not the case, I imagine there is some other reason this warning occurs. Perhaps too many people are used to defining main without a return 'main(){printf("hi");}', that they decided int is the default return value, and anything else must be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this. If you don't define a return type you are *not* defining a function. By definition a function declaration must have a return type. Think of forward declared functions. You always define a return type in both the forward declaration and the definition. Why? Because if you didn't it wouldn't fit the syntax of a function.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it wouldn't be necessary, logically speaking.

But C++ inherited its declarator syntax from C, in which a definition is also a declaration. A declaration requires a return type.

And, despite the obvious incompatibilities (member functions, for one), there was no reason to deliberately deviate from this.

If one were to write a brand new language, you could probably make it so that return types on definitions were optional, as long as definitions were not also declarations. Pre-definition declarations would become obligatory — a little cumbersome, if you ask me!